# How to aggregate to get average with same string in the field array

Tags: aggregation-framework

I have a problem here. This is my field in mongodb:

```
{"_id" : ObjectId("5c9c25b7ae9b9d188f088492"),
    "Title" : "PENERAPAN_DATA MINING PADA PENJUALAN MENGGUNAKAN METODE CLUSTERING STUDY KASUS PT",
    "Author" : "sutrisno",
    "Keywords" : [ 

        {
            "keywordName" : "mining",
            "keywordSkor" : 0.0119760479041916
        }, 
        {
            "keywordName" : "tampil",
            "keywordSkor" : 0.0119760479041916
        }, 
        {
            "keywordName" : "data",
            "keywordSkor" : 0.0114316820903647
        },  

    ],
    "Creator" : "sutrisno",
}

"_id" : ObjectId("5c9c28f8ae9b9d1e2ee4e158"),
    "Title" : "Jurnal Komputer dan Informatika (KOMPUTA)",
    "Author" : "Farid Fansuri",
    "Keywords" : [ 
        {
            "keywordName" : "data",
            "keywordSkor" : 0.0869158878504672
        }, 
        {
            "keywordName" : "mining",
            "keywordSkor" : 0.0308411214953271
        },
```

How to I get the average of the field `Keywords` which has same string 
**data** and **mining**

```
"Keywords" : [
    {
        "keywordName" : "mining",
        "keywordSkor" : 0.0308411214953271
    }, 
    {
        "keywordName" : "data",
        "keywordSkor" : 0.0119760479041916
    }, 
     {
        "keywordName" : "tampil",
        "keywordSkor" : 0.0119760479041916
    },
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite easy to achieve using aggregation framework :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$Keywords"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$Keywords.keywordName",
      avg: {
        $avg: "$Keywords.keywordSkor"
      }
    }
  }
])
```

will output :

```
[
  {
    "_id": "tampil",
    "avg": 0.0119760479041916
  },
  {
    "_id": "data",
    "avg": 0.04917378497041595
  },
  {
    "_id": "mining",
    "avg": 0.02140858469975935
  }
]
```